# how to write the regular expression patterns for the following scenarios

Tags: java, regex

Can any body give me some regular expression patterns which will extract the version numbers(1.5) from some sample strings like

```
    "jdk1.5","jdk-v1.5","jdk-V1.5","jdk V1.5","jdkv1.5","jdk version1.5","1.5.6","v1.5","V1.5","version 1.5","Version 1.5","14.5.4","1.5.4","14.5.4""jdj14.5"
```

I want to store the regex patterns in a string array and will check these patterns with the above strings. If there is a match with any of the stored patterns, then the output should be the version number 1.5. I want to extract the version numbers (1.5) only from the above strings.

valid string formats : 
      "jdk1.5","jdk-v1.5","jdk-V1.5","jdk V1.3","jdkv1.4","jdk version1.5","1.5.6","v1.5","V1.5","version 1.5","Version 1.5","14.5.4","1.5.4","14.5.4""jdj14.5","14.52.3.42"

Invalid String formats : "jdk1..2","jdk.1.2.",".1.2."

Comment: -1 for what amounts to a "Give me teh codez" question. *[what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Requirements

If you can formulize what you want as:

1. Anything in format `1.5` or `1.5.6` or `1.5.6.7` or `1.5.6.7.8` etc. is valid version number by default (numbers can be one or more digits like `12.60.70`).
2. A version number `1.5` can be followed by a dot (`.`) only if it is in the format `1.5.6`.
3. A version number `1.5` never preceded by a dot (`.`) like `.1.5`.

### Solution

Then, I can suggest you this regex:

```
(?!\.)(\d+(\.\d+)+)(?![\d\.])
```

See it [**in action**](http://regexr.com?31ut3), includes all positive samples and excludes all negative samples you provided.

### How to use

**First capture group** will be your version number. Sample code:

```
Pattern pattern    = Pattern.compile("(?!\\.)(\\d+(\\.\\d+)+)(?![\\d\\.])");
Matcher matcher    = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();

if (matchFound)
{
    String version = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println("Version number: " + version);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("No match for the input!");
}
```

**Note:** This will work only with Java 7+, because look-aheads doesn't supported by older versions.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur help... But still i want to match also 1.6.2 or any version numbers with periods... for example 1.2.5 or 1.2.5.6

Comment: OK, I changed my answer according to your last comments. See if it works.

Comment: Thanks... But the problem is it was matching the string 1.25.655. (see here there is a dot at the end). It was returning 1.25.65. But it is incorrect version number    :(   And can u explain me how to do write this in java. I want that matched version number as output.

Comment: Thanks for counter-examples, I fixed my answer properly and explained with sample code. Please, give me feedback about the results.

Comment: Hi mmdemirbas, Thanks for ur help in completing this issue. It was working fine. But there is some problem with the parsing again. If the string is "DB2 10.5 fix" it was returning 2 10.5. and if there are any years like "DB2 release 2009" it was returning 2009.. Can u please help me solving this last fix..   :(

Comment: @SrinivasB Sorry, I have forgotten to escape dot (`.`) in `(.\d+)`. Escaping it fixes these errors. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
^(jdk[- ]?)?([vV](ersion)? ?)?\d\.\d(\.\d)?$
```

You can ommit `[vV]` with `v` if you set `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

`(?<=([\w\s]))(\d)\.(\d)(.\d)?`

This will match all your valid formats , and not match any invalid format.

See it working here : http://regexr.com?31ubc

I would be grateful if someone can assist me in making it better, and also on how to make it
match `1.5.6`

Comment: @hsz yes, I have already mentioned that in answer and asked for suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed :) However you should use `^` and `$` to be sure that whole string is tested. If done, your regex does not works :-(

Comment: Hi i can have not only three precisions. but more than that like 1.2.3.4 or 14.5.6 is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

`(?<![\d.])(\d+[.])+(\d+)(?![\d.])`

Check this...

It will match the string of the form

`number.number.number.number`

not followed or preceded by a dot

Answer (score 0):

For Strings like 1.5.6 you can just use:
`[0-9](.[0-9])+`
http://regexr.com?31ubo

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex:

```
(^([jJ][dD][kK])([\s]*[vV]*\d+.\d+(.\d+)*))$
```

This would make your day :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to catch more than two numbers like "1.5.6" or "1.5.0" you can use

`[0-9](.[0-9])+`

Or if you only want the first two digits
`[0-9].[0-9]` , but this will not work on strings like 1.5.0.0, it will catch 1.5 and 0.0.

Comment: But it should take more than two precisions also.

Comment: The first regex also works for 1.5.6.6.7 or anything like (one digit Number).(oneDigitNumber)...